problem with ngnix Kubernetes gives 404 Not Found nginx although my service are working
here is my
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-serv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: posts.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /posts
          pathType: Prefix  
          backend:
            service:
              name: query-srv
              port:
                number: 4002

and i have running srv are
comment-srv             ClusterIP   10.111.4.115     <none>        4001/TCP   31h
event-bus-srv           ClusterIP   10.108.112.56    <none>        4005/TCP   33h
kubernetes              ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    46h
moderationservice-srv   ClusterIP   10.109.214.225   <none>        4003/TCP   31h
post-svc                ClusterIP   10.109.156.86    <none>        4000/TCP   32h
query-srv               ClusterIP   10.97.137.162    <none>        4002/TCP   31h

i tried for logging the deployment pods of query and  by using node port  in post -depl and checking form there all service are working fine

have you tried using curl localhost:4002/posts what does it say? before using nginx ingress try to check if the forwarded service port is working correctly or not on that specific path.
and what's your k8s version. if it's >1.18 then try to mention the following class name under spec
ingressClassName: nginx

And another thing try to expose your service to a specific port using NodePort. and then use that port on the ingress controller manifest file

when i use nodeport its working but when i also implemnet ingress on node port its not

Are you trying to use your clusterIP port on ingress controller? I mean you have to use NodePort or Load Balancer type of service and then you have to use that load balancer or nodeport services port on the ingress controller! you can also expose your deployment to a particular port using kubectl port-forward and then use that port on the ingress controller. But the best way is to use a load balancer type of service!

the problem has been solved by removing (uninstalling ) and installing ingress again ..

Oh ok nice that you have solved that problem yourself! Kudos!
